# Powershell running invoke-command on several servers using -Asjob but log completion log locally

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a powershell script that installs some software on a bunch of remote servers.
I am using the -Asjob option to run them synchronously.
I'm also using for loop to run the remote commands on each server, but i want to write a "Done" log file **locally where i am running the script** to notify me exactly when each server completes the commands.

This is the sample code i am testing, and the script runs fine, but the "Done" log files gets generated immediately, and not as each server finishes.

```
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
$servers = Get-Content -Path f:\temp\servers.txt

foreach($server in $servers) {
    Write-Verbose "Start batch file as a job on $server"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
    echo testfile1 > f:\temp\testfile1.txt
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
    echo testfile2 > f:\temp\testfile2.txt
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
    echo testfile3 > f:\temp\testfile3.txt
    echo DONE} > f:\temp\$server.done.txt -Asjob
}
```

thanks

Comment: The `-AsJob` switch parameter goes _before_ the redirection operator: `...} > f:\temp\$server.done.txt -Asjob` -> `...} -Asjob > f:\temp\$server.done.txt`

Comment: even putting -Asjob before the redirection, its the same results.. the $server.done file gets created immediately.

Comment: why are you using jobs? you can hand the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet a scriptblock and a list of target systems ... and the code will run in parallel on the target systems ... and the results will be returned to your system.

Comment: invoke-command server1,server2,server3 { whatever } # runs in parallel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the redirection operator after `Invoke-Command { ... }` - otherwise you'll be redirecting the resulting *job objects* to file, rather than the output from the jobs - instead, collect all the job objects to a variable `$jobs`:

```
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
$servers = Get-Content -Path f:\temp\servers.txt

$jobs = foreach($server in $servers) {
    Write-Verbose "Start batch file as a job on $server"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
    echo testfile1 > f:\temp\testfile1.txt
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
    echo testfile2 > f:\temp\testfile2.txt
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
    echo testfile3 > f:\temp\testfile3.txt
    echo DONE} -Asjob
}
```

Now that we've kicked off all the remoting jobs and collected the pertaining job object, we simply need to wait and then collect the output:

```
foreach($job in $jobs){
    # Wait for jobs to finish, retrieve their output
    $jobOutput = $job |Receive-Job -Wait 

    # Grab the remote server name from the output
    $server = $jobOutput |ForEach-Object PSComputerName |Select -First 1

    # Write output to file
    $jobOutput > f:\temp\$server.done.txt
}
```

Comment: thank you! this work brilliantly. very much appreciated!

Comment: @JohnnyCakes You're welcome. FWIW I'd not recommend doing this, simply pass all server names to `Invoke-Command` up front and let it handle the rest (like some people mentioned in the comments) :)

Comment: let me ask you this then.. what is the advantage of using -Asjob Vs just using invoke-command alone for multiple servers?

Comment: Apart from being able to inspect and wait for the individual jobs manually? Absolutely none:)